# Can I fix DNS issues on MBP for good?

Tags: macbook-pro, network, dns

I noticed DNS issue on my MBP where all of sudden (in the middle of my work, nothing changed) my DNS simply stops working. It's easy to notice that, so I do the following:

- first I check if DNS is really broken by eg pinging google.com, when DNS is not working, ping is not working either
- then I execute the script with following commands:

  ```
  sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist
  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist
  ```

This is all happening on MBP 2013 with Yosemite installed, sometimes more often, sometimes less.

Is there a way to fix DNS issues in more better, systematic, way; so I dont have to manually fix it by myself?

EDIT

Log:

```
15/2/3 15:01:11.693 Slack[9104]: dnssd_clientstub read_all(16) failed 0/4 0 
15/2/3 15:01:11.693 Slack[9104]: tcp_connection_host_start 424 DNSServiceCreateConnection failed: -65563
...
15/2/3 15:01:39.575 discoveryd[9083]: Basic ClientIPC,Warn Failed to create event source
```

Comment: sorry don't have any DNS log (how to get one?). I just go to terminal, as explained, and ping eg. `google.com`. If ping is not working, than I know my DNS broke again.

Comment: Hmm if the dns outage happens again just open /Utilities/Console click Show Log List if the list pane is hidden and choose 'System Log Queries' -> 'All Messages'. Now check/compare the point of time of the outage with the time stamps and/or look/search (search field: right upper corner) for messages containing 'dns' or 'discoveryd'. Copy and paste the result and add it to your question.

Comment: ok, will do that next time when this happens.

Comment: Nope, this one happens in the middle of working, so no waking up or anything like that (my 2nd problem is seriously affecting my the _other_ computer;)

Comment: Ive updated the message with the log

Comment: Have you updated to 10.10.2? It may solve your issue. In any case, you're not alone (see http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/01/why-dns-in-os-x-10-10-is-broken-and-what-you-can-do-to-fix-it/)

Comment: Im on 10.10.2. Yeah, I know I am not the only one :))) would like to see if someone fixed this in a better way :) Thank you!